# Does the PHP current() function return a copy or reference of array?

Tags: php, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I created a simple test case that replicates an issue I'm having.

I'm walking through a two dimensional array using the `next()` and `current()` functions, and am wanting to setup the array pointer to a specific location.  So, given a 2D array with a variable name of `$food` with the following array structure:

```
array
  0 => <-- POINTER LOCATION
    array
      0 => string 'apple' <-- POINTER LOCATION
      1 => string 'orange'
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string 'onion'
      1 => string 'carrot'
```

... And the following code snippet:

```
// move the inner array's pointer once
$should_be_orange = next(current($food));

// now check that inner array's value
$should_still_be_orange = current(current($food));
```

... Why is the value of `$should_be_orange` "orange" but the value of `$should_still_be_orange` "apple"?  Is this because the `current()` function returns a **copy** of the inner array, who's pointer gets iterated, and then destroyed (leaving the **original** array untouched)?  Or am I simply doing something wrong that I'm not catching?

At the root of the question, how do you move the inner array's pointer given that you don't know the outer array's key (and must use the `current()` function to obtain the outer array's pointer location)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `current()` returns an element from the array. In your case, this element is also an array, and that's why `next()` is working at all in your code. Your `next()` do not work on the `$food` array, but on copy of `$food[0]`, returned by `current()`

Comment: Okay, exactly what I suspected.  Assuming I always have a two dimensional array (like the example), do you have a suggestion on how I can move the pointer of the inner array?

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** pass function in arguments, you can must only variables, because argument is reference:

```
function current(&$array) {...}
function next(&$array) {...}
```

so proper syntax is:

```
// move the inner array's pointer once
$tmp = current($food);
$should_be_orange = next($tmp);

// now check that inner array's value
$tmp = current($food);
$should_still_be_orange = current($tmp);
                 ^^^^^^ NO! It should be "apple" ! When you do next($tmp) it will be orange !
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/YZfEAw

Documentation:

- [Next(&$array)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php)
- [Current(&$array)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php)

---

When you are learning PHP you should display ALL errors using command:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Using this u should receive notice:

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in (...) on line (...)
```

*(i think this answer need review cause of english gramma)*

Comment: The documentation is not in sync with the current implementation. You are supposed to pass variables to `next()` and `current()`, but expressions / array constants work too.

Comment: Yes it will work, but it will create Strict standards error as is mention above. Passing function instead of variable is main problem here.

Comment: In which version did you test that? Because it does neither in PHP 5.3 nor 5.4 for me. -- And no, the main problem is that no reference is *returned*, as OP already suspected.

Comment: Yes! All info is in documentation.